# CGFloat not defined in Foundation framework

Tags: ios, objective-c

In order to make it easier to write code for 64-bit architectures apple introduced quite a while ago `NSInteger` or `NSUInteger` data type. This data type is declared in foundation framework. So basically if I want to write code 64-bit clean using basic foundation framework I can do it easily. The problem appears if I want to use float 64-bit aka `CGFloat`. As I can understand all geometry functions, structures etc. were intended to be used in relation to user interface in case of `CGFloat` I don't understand why do I need to import UIKit framework. Is it sort of oversight from apple's side? Is it intentional? Is there anything equivalent to `CGFloat` in foundation?

Comment: It's defined in `CGBase.h` isn't it, not in `UIKit.h` directly?

Comment: Its a Core Graphics type. Why should you use it outside UIKit?

Comment: if you need a 64-bits floating point number, here we go: `Float64`.

Comment: @reecon True I have been sitting lately too much in core graphics and started, I think, abusing CGFloat a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into [64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html).

> **`CGFloat` changes size in 64-bit code.** The `CGFloat` type changes to a
>   64-bit floating point number. As with the NSInteger type, you cannot
>   assume that `CGFloat` is a float or a double. So use `CGFloat`
>   consistently.

`NSInteger`, `NSUInteger`, `CGFloat` - these will be 64 bits on 64-bit systems, and 32-bit on 32-bit systems.